# What should be the correct approach to pass in primary key into URL?

Tags: python, django

Right now I am using Class-based delete view, and my URL contains two arguments which are the primary keys of my 2 models: `Post` and `Lesson`. However, I am encountering an `Attribute Error: Generic detail view LessonDeleteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf`.

These are my two models `Lesson` and `Post`:

```py
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default0.jpg', upload_to='course_image/')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})

class Lesson(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="lesson/pdf")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

This is my URLs.py:

```py
path('post/<int:post_id>/lesson_uploaded/<int:lesson_id>', LessonDeleteView.as_view(), name='lesson_delete'),
```

Right now this is how I am trying to insert the parameters in my html template:

```html
{% block content %}
<div id="main">
    <table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
      <tr>          
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for l in Lesson %}
      <tr>
        <td>
            {% if l.file %}
                {{ l.title }}
            {% else %}                  
            <h6>Not available</h6>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>{{ l.post.author }}</td>
        <td>{% if l.file %}                 
            <a href="{{ l.file.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank">Download</a>
            {% else %}
            <h6>Not available</h6>
            {% endif %}    
        </td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'lesson_delete' post.id l.id %}">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my class-based view:

```
class LessonDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = Lesson
    success_url = '../'
    template_name = 'lesson_confirm_delete.html'
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you need two IDs. If you want to delete the lesson, you just need the lesson ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are deleting `Lesson`, you don't need to provide `Post` ID. You can simply use `Lesson` ID here. So try like this:

```
# url
path('post/lesson_uploaded/<int:pk>/', LessonDeleteView.as_view(), name='lesson_delete'),  # using pk instead of lession_id, it will resolve the error you are facing

# template
<td> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'lesson_delete' l.id %}">Delete</a>
</td>
```

#### Update

from comment section, you can override the delete method like this:

```
class LessonDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = Lesson
    success_url = '../'
    template_name = 'lesson_confirm_delete.html'

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.file.delete()  # <-- added file delete code
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Comment: thanks! anyway is there a way to delete the file in deleteview? The deleteview is working now but the files that were uploaded are still in the media file.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing the lesson id. 
Since Post gets deleted by default lesson would get deleted as well. Check this video to better understand how to pass the id and details on Delete View.

[DeleteView(Class Based Views)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40UjTHcs-zw&list=PLptRfvs8o8WY1jTJw6yQKVhRB5YMYt11O&index=12&t=0s)

Comment: i am trying to delete the specific lesson and not the post, and hence I would want to pass the primary key of the lesson. The video is not very informative as it does not touch on implementing id in url or within html templates.

Comment: Also you don't need post.id just the lesson id (l.id). just the lesson id is enough

this is url pattren I follow
url(r'^delete/,(?P<pk>\d+)/$' ,Delete.as_view(), name='delete'),